# Stop of exporting excel to pdf

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, export

Well, for last two months I've been exporting Excel worksheets to PDF and this morning my code just stopped doing that. Every other functionality of my application works great but when I run my "Excel to PDF" part it just **freezes whole application**. After this I've tried to debug it, but again it freezes it without showing any sign of what is the problem. Here is my code for that export:

```
xlSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, path + file_name, XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard, true, false, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, false, System.Type.Missing);
```

Any idea why is this happening or another way for export of excel2pdf?!

Comment: My Excel/VBE environment sometimes messes up with memory: the most trivial code doesn't work as expected, erratic behaviour etc. Usually restarting a computer helps.

Comment: Jüri Ruut, you're the man! It worked!

Comment: @JüriRuut: this may be worth an answer so that Sylca could accept it and this would "close" the question

Comment: Some extra points won't hurt :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Excel/VBE environment sometimes messes up with memory: the most trivial code doesn't work as expected, erratic behaviour etc. Usually restarting a computer helps.

Comment: Seriously? Rebooting was the answer? This is like a tech support hotline's dream ;-)

Comment: Happens after 3..4 days uptime and hibernations for my setup. XP Pro SP3, Excel 2003.